# Event listener on view in tabs when not extending TabActivity

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that extends a MapActivity, so I can't extend TabActivity. 
I am inflating the content of the tabs dynamically, and everything *looks* good.

The problem that I'm running in to is that I get a NullPointerException when trying to bind event listeners to the views that were inflated into a tab past the first tab.

*Example:*

```
myButtonInTab2 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.mybuttonintab2);
myButtonInTab2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void(View v){
        ///blah blah blah
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are "inflating the content of the tabs dynamically", you should be calling `findViewById()` on the result of the `inflate()` call, for any widgets in that tab.